# Makefile appears to not generate dependencies (.d)

Tags: c, makefile

I have a simple project so far.

```
src/main.c
src/core/interface/repl.c
src/core/interface/repl.h
```

But whenever I run `make` it doesn't generate any `.d` files. Am I missing something here?

```
NAME = database
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall

SRCS = \
    ${SRCDIR}/main.c \
    ${INTERFACE}/repl.c

SRCDIR = ./src
CORE = ${SRCDIR}/core
INTERFACE = ${CORE}/interface

OBJS = ${SRCS:.c=.o}
DEP = $(OBJS:%.o=%.d)

RM = rm -f

%.o: %.c
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $< -o ${<:.c=.o}

${NAME}: ${OBJS}
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${OBJS} -o ${NAME}

all: ${NAME}

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    ${RM} ${OBJS} ${NAME}

-include $(DEP)
```

Comment: You don’t tell the compiler to generate the dependencies.  You need something extra in `CFLAGS`.

Comment: I recommend reading this: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/

Comment: To tell gcc to generate .d files, add `-MMD` to `CFLAGS`.  There are variations, but that is generally the simplest.